# Spring cloud proxy service-to-service calls

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, microservices

Currently I have a frontend service that makes calls to a notification service. The frontend service does not depend on the response from the notification service. I want the frontend service to make a call to the notification, but not wait for a response from the notification service. Could do this within the frontend service itself? Do I have to use some messaging service that can 'proxy' the calls between the two services?

Answer (score 0):

You need a queue, the queue can be independent service (RabbitMq, Hornet, etc) o you can use a queue inside your notification service.

1. Independent Queue, in this case you can use a message broker in the middle of the services, the frontendservices send the message to the queue and the notification service read the message from the queue and then send it.
2. Internal Queue, you can have in your notification service an internal queue, like the queues in SpringIntegration. Whe the service receive a message inmediately put it on the queue and return an OK code. The frontendservice doesn't need to wait until the notification is send. Then the notification service process the messages in its queue on its own pace.

Comment: How about using an Internal Queue on the front-end service? The front-end service would not need to wait for the network call to complete and return a response quicker.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But you need to implement the same on every frontend service.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for asynchronous execution. Just add `@EnableAsync` to your application class and annotate the method calling the notification service with `@Async`.